# I'm trying to update object inside object in react hooks with useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to update object inside object in react hooks with `useState`.

When I create it's ok, but when I try to update only the `count` it's deleting the `neighbors`.

This is the console after create

> ```
> {fish1: {…}}
> fish1:
> count: 1
> neighbors: Array(1)
> 0: Array(3)
> 0: "fish3"
> 1: "fish6"
> 2: "fish7"
> ```

after the update

> ```
> {fish1: {…}}
> fish1:
> count: 2
> ```

This is the code that create or update

```
if (fishProfile.name in fishDictionary) {
  setFishDictionary({
    ...fishDictionary,
    [fishProfile.name]: {
      count: fishDictionary[fishProfile.name].count+1
    }
  })
} else {
  setFishDictionary({
    ...fishDictionary,
    [fishProfile.name]: {
      count: 1,
      neighbors: [fishProfile.Neighbors]
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(fishProfile.name in fishDictionary){
            setFishDictionary({...fishDictionary,[fishProfile.name]:{count:fishDictionary[fishProfile.name].count+1,neighbors:fishDictionary[fishProfile.name].neighbors } })
         }
        else
        {
        setFishDictionary({...fishDictionary,[fishProfile.name]:{count:1,neighbors:[fishProfile.Neighbors]}})
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mutating state and removing properties when updating the `fishDictionary` state. When updating React state it is necessary to shallow copy all state, and nested state, that is being updated.

```
setFishDictionary(fishDictionary => {
  if (fishProfile.name in fishDictionary) {
    return {
      ...fishDictionary,
      [fishProfile.name]: {
        ...fishDictionary[fishProfile.name], // <-- shallow copy
        count: fishDictionary[fishProfile.name].count + 1
      }
    };
  } else {
    return {
      ...fishDictionary,
      [fishProfile.name]: {
        count: 1,
        neighbors: [fishProfile.Neighbors]
      },
    };
  }
});
```